# How do I escape json like you escape output to prevent XSS

Tags: php, jquery, json

When you escape output you do it like this to prevent XSS:

```
      echo htmlentities( $variable );
```

do we need to escape a json object too to prevent XSS?:

```
      echo htmlentities( json_encode( $variable ) );
```

or is it not necessary, please could someone tell me. If its not needed, please explain why?

JQuery:

inside the success part of the ajax:

it will be in a $.each loop and the content will be:

```
    $('#textbox').attr( 'value', variable );
```

Comment: How you escape data depends on *where you are putting it*, not on what the data you are escaping is. We can't tell you what you need to do to the data, because we don't know where your `echo` statement appears.

Comment: JSON object is parsed to javascript/JQuery. and used to diplplay output, and sometimes put in text boxes.

Comment: "JSON object is parsed to javascript/JQuery" — That says nothing about where you are putting it. Just what processes it. That might mean you make an `application/json` HTTP response, or that you embed it as a `data-json` attribute value on a div, or that you embed it in the middle of a `<script>` element (and if you do that you might do so as a JS literal or as a JS string representation of JSON).

Comment: "sometimes put in text boxes" — And what is a text box? Do you mean the value attribute of an `input` element? Do you mean the textNode childNode of a `textarea` element?

Comment: yes that's correct value attribute of a input type text (text box html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> yes that's correct value attribute of a input type text (text box html).

You need to run it through `htmlspecialchars` (you could also use `htmlentities`, but that is overkill).

Characters with special meaning in HTML (such as `"` and `'`) may appear in JSON texts and will (if not escaped) act as "End of attribute value" characters in attributes delimited by the matching character.

```
<input value="{ "foo": 1 }">
                 ^^^^^^^^^^
                 this is an error
```

Comment: it will be in a $.each loop and the content will be: $('#textbox').attr( 'value', variable );

Comment: Then you aren't outputting HTML and the DOM will handle the escaping for you. That said, you should use `$('#textbox').val(variable)` rather then fiddling with `attr` for this.

Answer (score 0):

No. JSON-encoded output is safe. All potentially harmful characters or input types are properly escaped or quoted.

Comment: That may or may not be true depending on where the JSON text is being echoed too. (e.g. it is not true if it is being echoed into an HTML attribute value)